# flutter Column mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min not working in TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 1,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(56),
                child: AppBar(
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        text: "tab1",
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: const [
                        Text('text'),
                      ],
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is what im getting, it fills the entire screen:

[image: get]

My expected results should look like this:

[image: expected]

What is the reason for this and how do I change it to the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on UI, the code structure will be

```dart
body: TabBarView(
  children: [
    Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('text'),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

In flutter parent position the children